# How to replace a date in string with human-readable date in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string what I get from the server which looks like:

```
You blocked until 2022-01-01T11:00:00.350Z
```

And now I want to convert it to human-readable date like

```
2022-01-01 11:00
```

For this I tried to find the date first:

```
let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.date]
if let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue) {
  let range = NSMakeRange(0, message.count)
  let matches = detector.matches(in: message, 
options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), 
range: range)

if !matches.isEmpty {
   for match in matches {
      print(match.date)

      let aSubstring = NSString(string: message).substring(with: match.range)
      print(aSubstring)
   }
}
}
```

So as a result `match.date` returned me `2022-01-01 11:00:00 +0000` but the result of `aSubstring` is `until 2021-08-02T11:38:10.214Z`.
So I'm curious why it includes `until` into the substring and how can I avoid that?

Comment: @matt thank you! Could you please help me with regex for this `2022-01-01T11:00:00.350Z` string? I am so bad with RegEx and cannot open another SO question for the next 90 minutes. I would be so grateful!

Comment: Actually if it's always the last word of the phrase, you don't need regex or search at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to extract the ISO8601 string omitting seconds, fractional seconds and the time zone with Regular Expression and then get the first 10 (date) and the last 5 characters (time)

```
let string = "You blocked until 2022-01-01T11:00:00.350Z"
if let range = string.range(of: "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}", options: .regularExpression) {
    let trimmedString = String(string[range])
    let humanReadable = "\(trimmedString.prefix(10)) \(trimmedString.suffix(5))"
    print(humanReadable) // 2022-01-01 11:00
}
```

However there is a caveat: The date is in UTC. If you want the date to be displayed in the current time zone you have to use a date formatter (actually two)

```
let string = "You blocked until 2022-01-01T11:00:00.350Z"
if let range = string.range(of: "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", options: .regularExpression) {
    let trimmedString = String(string[range]) + "Z"
    let inputFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    if let date = inputFormatter.date(from: trimmedString) {
        let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        outputFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        outputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        let humanReadable = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
        print(humanReadable)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the date part is at the end of the string, then
you could try something a bit more convoluted but workable. Something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt = ""

    func humanDate(_ str: String) -> String? {
        // convert the string to a date
        let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        // re-format the date to your liking
        if let date = dateFormatter1.date(from: str) {
            let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    // dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy MMMM EEEE HHa:mm" // even more human readable                
            return dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(txt).onAppear {
            
            let inputString = "You blocked until 2022-01-01T11:00:00.350Z"
            if let dateStr = inputString.split(separator: " ").last {
                if let theDate = humanDate(String(dateStr)) {
                    print("\n----> " + theDate + "\n")
                    txt = theDate
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```